# convert a while-loop into a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I convert this while-loop into a function, so I can call it multiple times.

```
i = 0
numbers = []
while i < 6:
    print "At the top of i is %d" % i
    numbers.append(i)


    i = i + 1
    print "Numbers now: ", numbers
    print "At the bottom i is %d" % i

print "The numbers: "

for num in numbers:
    print num
```

Comment: This is actually a very valid and interesting question. Not in the context the OP asked, but for dynamic code creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def fun_name():
    i = 0
    numbers = []
    while i < 6:
        print "At the top of i is %d" % i
        numbers.append(i)
        i = i + 1
    print "Numbers now: ", numbers
    print "At the bottom i is %d" % i

    print "The numbers: "

    for num in numbers:
        print num
```

you can add, remove part of code you need. You can also return some value to use in main program.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_numbers(N):
  i = 0
  numbers = []
  while i < N:
    print ("At the top of i is %d", i)
    numbers.append(i)
  
  i = i + 1
  print ("Numbers now: ", numbers)
  
  print ("At the bottom i is %d", i)
```

```
for num in numbers:
    print(num)
```

But there is already such function in python and this function is `range`.